# Setting window.location with &copy anywhere in the URL changes to © in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In IE11, using `window.location`, `window.location.href`, and `document.location` all have the same effect. If the query string in the URL you set contains `&copy` anywhere, it will be changed into `©`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

To see a demo of this issue, save the following text into a file called `test.html` and open it in IE11. (This bug may affect other versions as well; I don't know.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<body>
    <div><a href="#" class="broken">Broken in IE11</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="works">Works in IE11</a></div>
    <p>Query string: <pre id="queryString"></pre></p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var queryString = (function() {
            if (!window.location.search) {
                return({});   // return empty object
            }
            var parms = {};
            var temp;
            var items = window.location.search.slice(1).split("&");   // remove leading ? and split
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                temp = items[i].split("=");
                if (temp[0]) {
                    if (temp.length < 2) {
                        temp.push("");
                    }
                    parms[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
                }
            }
            return(parms);
        })();

        $(function() {
            $('#queryString').text(JSON.stringify(queryString));

            $('.broken').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location = "test.html?q=test&copy=true";
            });
            $('.works').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location = "test.html?copy=true&q=test";
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue affects all IE versions, and that there is no fix or workaround that allows the exact URL to work; you must change the URL.

URL-encoding names and values in the query string is sufficient. Modifying the sample above to use `%63opy` instead of `copy` causes the correct URL to be loaded.

See also: [Accidental HTML entities in URLs](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200812/accidental_html_entities_in_urls.html)